# Image gets disappeared in Ionic Virtual Scrolling in Android and IOS devices

Tags: firebase, ionic3

I am using Ionic version 3 in one of the project and I have used ion-list in which the images gets rendered from firebase. Everything works fine on the browser but as soon as I build the apk, only the first few images gets rendered properly and on virtual scrolling (infinite scrolling) the images blinks and disappears.

My code hierarchy is as follows:-

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-card>
       <ion-col>
          <div>
             <ion-row>
                  <img/>
             </ion-row>
         </div>
      </ion-col>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

I have used img tag for the images to load. I tried every possible solution but not able to crack it.

I have also tried the following things to solve this: 1) Tried changing the position of img tag. 2) Tried using ion-img tag. 3) Tried perfect-scrollbar module of npm 4) Followed this link masteringionic.com/blog/… 5) Tried to find the trace of any event bubbling. After trying all of these, I seek your help if any.

Thanks in advance for the solution!

Comment: even if you will fix this image rendering problem ... there are lot of other problems associated with virtual scrolling .. it's good for simple cards but for complex card .. i will suggest don't go with virtual scrolling... there might be a solution but when i got stuck there i was unable to find a solution even after trying searching solution for days... no proper support from ionic team ... i bet no one will answer your question. a lot of questions are still unanswered.

Comment: Somehow the issue was due to the stepper component that I used on top of the <ion-card> tag. If I remove the <ion-stepper> then everything works fine. I think this is something related to event bubbling on ionic tags.

Comment: please post a working code here as an answer .... both html and ts code plz ...it will be very helpful for others !!!! Thanks !!!